# Understanding CSS letter-spacing: is it valid to replace the default value of normal with 0?

Tags: html, css, letter-spacing

According to [this page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/), the CSS **letter-spacing** property has a default value of **normal**.

Notably, non-default values are added to the default value:

> The most important point to note when using letter-spacing is that the
>   value specified does not change the default, it is added to the
>   default spacing the browser applies (based on the font metrics).
>   letter-spacing also supports negative values, which will tighten the
>   appearance of text, rather than loosening it.

According to this definition, **0** should be equivalent to the default value of **normal** since 0 + X = X.

1) Is it valid to use **0** as a replacement for the default value of **normal**? (This is for a slider implementation.)

2) Why isn't **0** the default value? Why introduce another value (i.e., **normal**)?

[This test on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJrvLq) also suggests a value of **0** is, indeed, equivalent to the default value of **normal**.

```css
.loose {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.tight {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.zero {
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.normal {
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>This type has no additional letter-spacing applied.</p>

<p class="loose">This type is letter-spaced loosely at <code>2px</code>.</p>

<p class="tight">This type is letter-spaced tightly at <code>-1px</code></p>

<p class="zero">This type is letter-spaced at <code>0</code></p>

<p class="normal">This type is letter-spaced at <code>normal</code></p>
```

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#letter-spacing-property:
*normal
No additional spacing is applied. Computes to zero.*  - It's just a keyword value

Comment: @Pete so you're saying **normal** and **0** are equivalent, right?

Comment: I assume so as that's the latest published version of css text module 3 and makes no mention of the user agent - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#keywords

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No both aren't *exactly* equivalent. If you check [the current specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-letter-spacing)

> normal
>
> The spacing is the normal spacing for the current font. **This value allows the user agent to alter the space between characters in order to justify text**.

Then

> `<length>`
>
> This value indicates inter-character space in addition to the default space between characters. Values may be negative, but there may be implementation-specific limits. **User agents may not further increase or decrease the inter-character space in order to justify text.**

In most of the cases, they will render the same but as you can read, the user agent doesn't handle both the same.

---

The definition in [the Draft of the next level](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#letter-spacing-property) seems to have changed slightly and both are now the same.

> For legacy reasons, a computed letter-spacing of zero yields a resolved value (getComputedStyle() return value) of normal..

You can also read here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1484

> CSS2 used to treat normal different than 0, so computing differently was a requirement. Now that the spec treats them the same ...

---

I don't know if all the browsers are already implementing this level but you can most likely consider them the same

Comment: so in CSS2, it only differs for `text-align: justify`

Comment: @gsnedders yes it *may* differ with justify (not necessarely). Unfortunately I cannot proove it, I am trying to find if I can get a working example to show this difference.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Mozzila docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing#Values

> The normal letter spacing for the current font. Unlike a value of 0, this keyword allows the user agent to alter the space between characters in order to justify text.

Seems like `0` is more of a hard value to set it to the default. Normal can be modified by the user agent.